# Using REGEXP in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr, regexp-replace

I have a column filled with this type of data

```
AR001-330110092522102
AR001-330335000041402
AR001-330410092999901
```

Problem is, I only want the numbers after the dash
my desired output is

```
330110092432102
330335091341402
330410092015901
```

How do I use `REGEXP` in oracle to accomplish this

Column name is `identifier` and table name is `NSUS`

Comment: Whilst you could use a REGEXP function I would consider using the standard functions in this case as REGEXP can add a lot of overhead to your query and you don't actually NEED the power of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use select [`regexp_substr`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) with `'[^-]+$'` pattern as :

```
select regexp_substr('AR001-330110092522102','[^-]+$') as "Result String" from dual
```

where

- [^-] points out the starting point except for the character(dash) within
  the list
- $    Matches the end of a string.
- Matches one or more occurrences.

Another option would be using [`regexp_replace`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php) :

```
select regexp_replace('AR001-330110092522102','(.*)\-(.*)','\2') as "Result String" from t
```

Indeed, you can also use `substr()`, `instr()` and `length()` functions combination to extract those strings such as

```
with t(str) as
(select 'AR001-330110092522102' from dual)
select substr(str,instr(str,'-')+1,length(str)) as "Result String" from t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7fb6ab65b2bebcf06e5b3f29629ac079)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very basic regular expression: `.*`
This means "accept any characters" - you just need to tell it to start after the `'-'` in the string, the position of which you can get using the `INSTR` function. So you end up with:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, '.*', INSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, '-')+1)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8ec24ebb2f9275f6875eb22a4bfef3b1)

Answer (score 0):

The regexp that you are looking for is: -([0-9])+$

This means that you are looking for in the end of the string a "-" and at least one number. The "$" represents in the end of the string.

Then to get your number use $1 (this is your capture group)

Use this to test: https://regex101.com/r/f9kwXV/17

EDIT: I'm not sure if this works this way in oracle. Example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('AR001-330335000041402', '-([0-9])+$', '$1')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Hey, Is still don't quite get it
can you give me an example please